# iBATIS - Request and Session Scope

Tags: java, spring, ibatis

I came across the following comment from Larry Meadors [here](http://markmail.org/message/6axlvagqkvfkqmcw#query%3a+page:1+mid%3at7fhgbothinqwkpg+state%3aresults)

> With readOnly="true" and
>   serialize="false", you are only going
>   to **cache within the current session**,
>   and the cache will be mutable. If you
>   want longer cache life, make
>   serialize="true".
>
> Also, you may want to just use the
>   MEMORY cache, and set the reference
>   type to HARD. That will keep
>   everything in memory even after a GC.
>
> Larry

I wanted to know what does `request` and `session scope` mean with respect to `iBATIS`? I understand these terms with respect to a Web Application but not from `iBATIS` cache point of view.

FWIW, I am using `iBATIS` with `Spring` support (using the wrapper classes that Spring provides) in a web application.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the author was discussing the use of iBatis in the context of a web application.